# Align everything to the top when used object-fit: contain;

Tags: css

I'm trying make an image occupy entire view area while retaining its aspect ratio.
`object-fit: contain;` seems to do the trick, except regardless of the window size, the image occupy entire height, pushing everything outside of view area.

```css
.resize img
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: 50% 0;
}

.resize
{
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 100px; /* inital demo size */
  height: 170px; /* inital demo size */
}
```

```html
<div class="resize">
  <span>
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/taykG37GWDgY-FGkdogDvsHSJMUGRMvkuVRT6yR-5UNkKvGRKeRlpGYXlslocOcS0txlfUdGW59JGtzADknxbMqnh6AtVCv9EXyB8nHp80YsRNA0Yw=w1024-h683-n-l50-sg-rj">
  </span>
  <div>myText</div>
</div>
```

How can I make the image fit into view area (red box), without leaving empty space below it?

| Expected Result | Actual Result |
| --- | --- |
| [image: expected] | [image: actual] |
| [image: expected] | [image: expected] |

Comment: @JaswinderKaur `cover` will truncate the image

Answer (score 0):

```css
span {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.resize img
{
    width: inherit;
    height: min-content;
    object-fit: scale-down;
    object-position: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 350px;
    max-height: max-content;
}

.resize
{
 overflow: auto;
resize: both;
border: 2px solid red;
min-height:250px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="resize" style="width:100px;">
      <span>
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/taykG37GWDgY-FGkdogDvsHSJMUGRMvkuVRT6yR-5UNkKvGRKeRlpGYXlslocOcS0txlfUdGW59JGtzADknxbMqnh6AtVCv9EXyB8nHp80YsRNA0Yw=w1024-h683-n-l50-sg-rj">
      </span>
      <div>myText</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: When width is greater than height, the image does not fit.

Comment: please check this edited answer

Comment: It still truncates image when width is bigger than height.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS grid to define two rows, one for the image and the other for the text

```css
.resize img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: 50% 0;
}

.resize {
  overflow: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0,1fr) auto;
  resize: both;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="resize" style="width:100px;height:170px;">
  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/taykG37GWDgY-FGkdogDvsHSJMUGRMvkuVRT6yR-5UNkKvGRKeRlpGYXlslocOcS0txlfUdGW59JGtzADknxbMqnh6AtVCv9EXyB8nHp80YsRNA0Yw=w1024-h683-n-l50-sg-rj">
  <div>myText</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is close, but it still leaves "empty space below image, pushing text to the bottom of the area.

Comment: @vanowm remove the fixed height from the container. You are setting explicit height/width to the container

Comment: Removing height will result in image resized beyond the visible area when width is larger than height.

Comment: @vanowm remove the height of the container not the image

Comment: The container width/height is set by the browser during resizing. If removed and window resized instead of container, it still resizes image height beyond visible area.